# Why my python always run the file of another package

Tags: python-3.x

My code does not import that file, it only imports three modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import calendar
```

And I find that when I delete the code `import pandas as pd` it works and runs the real file that I want to run. And I am sure that I closed other running files. I need pandas, and change `pd` into other names does not help. How can I prevent such things from happening? I use the pycharm and such things did not happen before when I use the pandas. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I solved it. That is because I set a folder as the source folder so that every time when I run other codes, it would run the files in this course folder first.

Answer (score 0):

That is because I set a folder as the source folder so that every time when I run other codes, it would run the files in this course folder first.